# Jquery and ajax delete conformation box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i need a ok / cancel delete confirmation dialogue box before i send ajax request in order to remove item from database

```
var id=ID;  
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sample.aspx?Mode=Delete",
    data: { id: id },
    success: function (response) {                  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use Javascript's `confirm` function. This is the easiest approach :)

```
var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
if (r == true) {
  var id=ID;  
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "sample.aspx?Mode=Delete",
      data: { id: id },
      success: function (response) {}             
  });
} else {
  // Do something if they push cancel button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery UI plugins.
Then just before the ajax function you need to do this:

```
$('a.deleteBtn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ** get you values here **

    $('div.deleteDialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 'auto',
        buttons: {
            "Delete": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: url,
                        data: {****},

                        success: function () {

                        },

                        error: function () {

                    });

                }, 1000);
            },

            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In youy  html file you need to add the dialog

```
 <div class="deleteDialog" title="Package Delete Confirmation" style="display: none">
        Are you sure you want to delete this?
    </div>
```